# Issue with type of Custom Select Component: Error When Using Generic Type <T,> with Comma vs. <T> Without Comma

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have created a custom select component that extends the HTML select element. I utilized a generic type to accommodate various data types, and I came across an unusual error. The error persists when I use <T,> with a comma, as shown here.

[with comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxgRc.png)

However, if i remove the comma, changing <T,> to , an error occurs everywhere, as shown here.

[without comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgeR9.png)

What causes this problem ?

Comment: Can you show us your `tsconfig.json`, you need to Ensure that your typeScript configuration is set up correctly.

Comment: [code block]{"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your code, whether with the comma or without

the comma in the generics is needed because otherwise there would be a collapse of 2 identical syntaxes in the tsx files

therefore, as a compromise, when you make a component that accepts only one generic, put the comma to make the parser understand that it is a generic and not a component

Comment: thanx for information